# how to select query tables column with objects in query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

i am joining two tables with query builder. here is the sample

```
$events = DB::table('eventcalenders')
        ->select('eventcalenders.id','eventcalenders.event_name',)
        ->join('countries', 'eventcalenders.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')->get();
```

can i declare an object of eventcalender as e and select with object name like 'e.id','e.event_name'.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after the query you need to loop through them since they are more than one item:

```
foreach($events as $e){
   $name = $e->event_name;
}
```

If you want to select only the first one that meets your constrains then use `.first()`.

```
$event = DB::table('eventcalenders')
        ->select('eventcalenders.id','eventcalenders.event_name',)
        ->join('countries', 'eventcalenders.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')->first();
$name = $event->event_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $events = DB::table('eventcalenders') 
           ->select('eventcalenders.id','eventcalenders.event_name','countries.*') 
           ->join('countries', 'eventcalenders.country_id', '=', 'countries.id') 
           ->get();
```

Afetr getting results

```
 foreach($events as $event)
 {
   echo $event->event_name;
   echo $event->country_name; //your specific field
 }
```